# InitializeControls() not found in Context

Tags: development, asp.net

I am having problem that the InitializeControls() is not working

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

    base.OnInit(e);
    InitializeControls();

}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the error? Is it a webpart code?

Comment: Yes it is a webpart code and InitializeControls() cannot be found in current context.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of file structure in visual studio? please provide in expanded file structure

Comment: you have written `InitializeControls()` instead of `InitializeControl()`

Comment: Yash i have use it but still same error

Comment: Gauravs i cant upload it here

Comment: you can upload it.... it will come to us a link... If not then upload the screenshot on image hosting site and share the link with us

Comment: Uploaded please check

Comment: last question, is it a visual webpart?

Comment: Yes it is a visual webpart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few points you need to make corrections

- InitializeControl() instead of InitializeControls()
- You will find a ".ascx.g.cs" file once you expand '.ascx" file.
- Change the namespace to same as in ".ascx.cs" file.
- make sure you have same class name in both the files. Replace if it is displaying some other class name in ".ascx.g.cs" file. Replace it where ever you find it in that file.

This should be enough to get your issue resolved.

Comment: i cant find the ".ascx.g.cs" file once you expand '.ascx" file.

Comment: in Visual studio, above your solution you have a search box. search for ".ascx.g.cs" in it

Comment: Do keep a copy of your code before any changes. Now Do Ctrl+Shift+ H.
Enter "VisualWebPart1" in Find block & provide "EditAdvertisement" in Replace block . Hit Ok

Comment: No its not there.

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: Doesnot find it in entire solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31634/discussion-between-gaurravs-and-shahroz-shaikh).

Comment: If you don't find it then check this link: http://samer-othman.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-fix-error-name-initializecontrol.html

Comment: I HAVE ALREADY TRIED IT yASH BUT PROBLEM IS STILL THERE

Comment: Anyone online ??

Comment: can you paste the entire <module> tag from element.xml of your webpart in chat section

Comment: I have past it there